# Hardware requirements for GRASS 7

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.0, hardware, system-requirements

I need to know the minimum hardware requirements to run GRASS 7, at the request of a Journal editor. There is plenty of information in the Wiki about [software requirements](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Software_requirements_specification), but none on hardware.

All I could find is this [unsigned message from 20 years ago](https://www.gislounge.com/system-requirements-for-grass/) at GisLounge:

> 8 Mbytes of memory (of course, more is better..)
>
> 100 Mbytes of free disk space
>
> ~40 mb for executables,
>
> ~40 mb for source code (which you can ignore if you merely install the
>   Linux binaries)
>
> ~? for data (the veritable bottomless pit can be filled with data, if
>   you so choose)

Naturally, things might be a little different by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a digest of a discussion that took place at the [GRASS users mail list](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2017-June/076646.html):

- GRASS should run on any **32-bit CPU**. It likely runs on 16-bit CPUs too, but that is something no one has tried in many years.
- It is not known for sure the minimum RAM requirements, but users report successfully running the GRASS console on systems with as low as **256 MB of RAM**.
- For actual processing RAM requirements are mostly a function of the size of input maps. However, many modules can be run using a low RAM set up, by configuring the GRASS_VECTOR_LOWMEM environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/source/REQUIREMENTS.html) includes details about the hardware requirements to compile GRASS 7.2, which includes:

- 800 MB of free disk space.
- The source code package needs disk space of around 26 MB compressed and 440MB uncompressed.
- The resulting binaries may need between 20 MB and 180 MB depending on your platform and compiler flags.
- During a full compilation you may need temporarily up to 550MB including the source code.

Comment: I am asking the minimum hardware requirements to ***run*** GRASS, not to compile it.

Comment: See https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2017-June/076652.html